# C++ exceptions - what isn't acting as it should

Tags: c++, c++11

I've been bragging a friend of mine about C++ (scopes and RAII and static typing ftw) (I'd be embarrassed if this were me and not ask :P) but as I'm looking at it I am puzzled as tp what is going wrong. I hope you guys can help. She's coming from Java hence the CamcelCase

ListIndexOutOfBoundsException.h

```
#ifndef LISTINDEXOUTOFBOUNDSEXCEPTION_H_
#define LISTINDEXOUTOFBOUNDSEXCEPTION_H_
#include <exception>
namespace Structures {
class ListIndexOutOfBoundsException: public ::std::exception {
public:
    ListIndexOutOfBoundsException(int index, int length);
    virtual const char* what() const noexcept;
    virtual ~ListIndexOutOfBoundsException() noexcept;
private:
    const char* errorString;
};
}



#endif /* LISTINDEXOUTOFBOUNDSEXCEPTION_H_ */
```

ListIndexOutOfBoundsException.cpp

```
#include "ListIndexOutOfBoundsException.h"
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
namespace Structures {
using ::std::stringstream;

ListIndexOutOfBoundsException::ListIndexOutOfBoundsException(int index,int length) {
    stringstream errorText("List index (");
    errorText<<index<<") out of bounds! (list length: "<<length<<")";
    errorString = errorText.str().c_str();
}

const char* ListIndexOutOfBoundsException::what() const noexcept {
    return errorString;
}

ListIndexOutOfBoundsException::~ListIndexOutOfBoundsException() noexcept {
    delete errorString;
}


}
```

When thrown this happens:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 
'Structures::ListIndexOutOfBoundsException'
 what():  OfBoundsException
```

I cannot work out where "OfBoundsException" has come from. What is going on!?

Comment: As remyabel noted earlier, `delete errorString` is wrong too. In C++ you rarely need `delete`, because there's usually a better alternative. But more importantly, even when you use it, it should be for an object allocated by `new`. That's not the case here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this

```
errorString = errorText.str().c_str();
```

errorText was a local object to the constructor that went out of scope and freed the memory it was using for it's c_str().

Try replacing errorString with a `char errorString[SomeLimit];` and using basic string operations to write to it. Using a stringstream is somewhat overly complex for an exceptionhandler.

Answer (score 4):

When the constructor goes out of scope, `errorText` no longer points to valid data, so all bets are off when you call `what()` (it invokes undefined behavior).  The easiest fix is to derive from `std::runtime_error`, as that keeps a `std::string` (or equivalent) which is valid for the lifetime of the exception.

Comment: Well, you might consider index out of bounds to be a logic_error rather than a runtime_error, but the same applies.